# Process Builder issues with updating opportunity name?

Tags: process-builder, process

So I keep running into this issue. I have set up two separate checkboxes for updating and creating an opportunity with data in this custom object. The only problem I'm running into is naming the opportunity. I have this formula set up that references the fields I want to use to name the opportunity.[image] but it keeps naming it 
"**myVariable_current.Account__c - myVariable_current.New_or_Used__c - myVariable_current.Model__c**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do concatenation in a formula across fields, you need to use the `&` operator

```
[Filemaker_Quote__c].Account__c & '-' & ...
```